# Creating database to accomodate sensor data per session on SQLite/Room anyhing?

Tags: android, database, google-cloud-platform, android-sqlite

I am struggling with creating Android database for my app. Below is the picture of the data I need to save/store based on the location.

**On Device:** I need to store sensor which comes at a frequency of 100Hz. User is going to use the app app for few hours which means there is going to be a lot of sensor data. If user is going to use the app multiple times (multiple session) after short breaks then I need to store data sensor data perssion wise on device.

**What I was thinking:** Create SQlite database and create a table and add column dynamically and add sensor data to that column. Each column is session. col 1 = session 1, col 2 = session 2 etc. 
Is it bad to do like this then what you guys would suggest?

**In cloud:** Now, how should I go about creating database if this data is going to get stored on cloud (GoogleCloudPlatform specifically) per user per session wise sensor data.

Any suggestion is welcomed. Please don't mark it as broad question because I am looking for efficient method to achieve this.

Refer the image below for further explanation or ask me for further explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to youse RoomDB as per your requirement and consider the facts. Because Room provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow fluent database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.

Apps that handle non-trivial amounts of structured data can benefit greatly from persisting that data locally. The most common use case is to cache relevant pieces of data. That way, when the device cannot access the network, the user can still browse that content while they are offline. Any user-initiated content changes are then synced to the server after the device is back online.

Also, I prefer to use firebase realtime DB along with room for better efficiency and reliability. If you are using roomDb and firebase for cloud storage you can use a single entity for both firebase and roomDb. It will also help you write less code and better reliability.

Because Room takes care of these concerns for you, I highly recommend using Room instead of SQLite.

For reference, Please go through this link [Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Comment: thank you for your reply but can elaborate more how RoomDB can be applied to what I am asking for. I mean how should I use it. Even a surface level description would help me at some extent.